# Html/Javascript - How do I block every EU country except the UK, and allow all non EU countries

Tags: javascript, html

I want a page to block EU countries except the UK, while allowing all other non-EU countries. How can this be done?

Comment: Why in the world would you need to do this?

Comment: @positlabs - Maybe to do with [VAT MOSS](https://remysharp.com/2014/12/16/vatmoss)

Comment: Correct in one Alohci. If I am hoping for a couple of hundred pounds, the last thing I want to do is go through all the hassle of VAT MOSS registration, when just blocking non-UK EU countries means I do not need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML is rendered and Javascript is run on the client side (unless you're using something like Node, but I'd expect a tag for it in that case) and for that reason you cannot reliably deny access to specific users (if you had a reliable IP-region-to-country database) using those technologies alone.
You *will* need a server-side component.

Comment: Thanks Nit, I will start another question but relating to PhP.